# XML Slideshow, each slide plays audio

Tags: jquery, xml, html, audio, slideshow

I am trying to create a student profile slideshow where each slide will be the image of the student and a voice over audio played with each image. My idea is to use XML to hold the info for each student: student pic, degree, and audio voice over file.
I need help if the audio voice can be done with the XML slideshow.
Can someone help me create an XML image and audio slideshow? I want to use XML because I can have 10 students/slides or 100 slides or more.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow and nice story... What is your actual question?

Comment: Can someone help me create an XML image and audio slideshow?
I want to use XML because I can have 10 students/slides or 100 slides or more.